# Keep socket connection between activities on android

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm developing an application on android 3.1 and I have an Activity A that has a subclass extending from aSyncTask, this subclass create a socket and connect to a server. All my communication is good. I received messages and send commands to a server, but when I got a specific command I have to start a second activity (activity B) but I can't lost my socket and the establish communication with the server, plus I have to still able to receive and send commands from activity B to server. How can I do that??
Any help please!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My approach is implementing a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) and move/centralise all your network connection code into service, for all activities that want to use socket connection, bind your network service in onCreate() then after finish unbind it in onDestory()

Comment: This is the correct way to do things. You should do all long running tasks (like maintaining an open socket connection) in the background with a service.

Comment: Thanks York and Kurtis, I'll do that!!

Comment: I have another question. Should I use a Service or an IntentService? If I have to use a Service, should I use a bound or Start Service?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Incidentally, OP, you should set this one as answered. He answered your original question.

Comment: This is not the recommended practice according to the android developer site. Posted an alternative answer.

Comment: Thanks, this answer has helped me a bunch! +1 for you!

Answer (score 10):

According to Dianne Hackborn (Android engineer), the recommended practice to pass network connections between activities is to create a singleton that any activity can access and manage the connection from there. See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-developers/yxOzuMGlcSo) and check the first post by Dianne.

The [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Basics) page on the android developers site (side note under the 'Basics' Section) also mentions that you should only use a service if you need to run code that needs to continue execution while your application is in the background.