# Presist an opened Socket between two processes in Android

Tags: android, sockets

Is there a way to share an opened socket in one process( application) with another process in Android?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not really do what you are asking.  You should take a look at

[How to pass socket, inputstream, outputstream objects between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137223/how-to-pass-socket-inputstream-outputstream-objects-between-activities)

and

[Android passing objects between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696684/android-passing-objects-between-activities)

You can use an object to save state data for an application upon it's reopening, but there is no way to share non serializable data between activities in android from what I understand.

You should use a service to do what you're asking instead of depending on an object.  See:

[Keep socket connection between activities on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783127/keep-socket-connection-between-activities-on-android)