# How to share a socket class instance between activities in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, android-service, parcelable

I want to create a socket object and I want to access it from another activity, how can I save this object(socket) and be able to get it through different activities

Comment: You can't. Create your socket inside a Service and bind both activity to it.

Comment: @rciovati but I need to use the socket in another activity, how could I do that?

Comment: @DiegoPalomar I am not using a service in my code, ,I am sending and receiving data from a server, and I want to use it in another acivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects passed between activities through Bundle must be serializable and socket, inputstream, outputstream aren't.

What you have to do is implement a **[Service](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html&ei=Hc2DUqWHKqzQ7AaFoYG4BA&usg=AFQjCNFwa_Qocx5ioFUPcqlqaUfnTYRndQ&sig2=gqpLg2w3X_czDvIBTCnPPw&bvm=bv.56343320,d.ZGU)** that contain the Socket and bind activities to service to work with the socket. Check the **[Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)** documentation to understand how you can do it.

Comment: is it necessary to use a service? is there another way?

Comment: A socket is not serializable, you will have to use a service ;)

Comment: Implementing your own `Application` class could also be a solution: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: That's definitely not a good idea, Application class have been designed to let developer maintain global application state and not for share complex objects like sockets.

Comment: According to Dianne Hackborn (Android engineer) it is inadvisable to use a service to persist a network connection. See this answer on a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/22644327/875806